# Max Sum of row within date range - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets.
I have names in first column, dates in first row, and numbers for each name/date.

[image: copy of slide]

I want to return the name and sum of numbers for the person who's sum of numbers is the largest (within date range.)

A cell formula for this would be better than a script.

It sounds straight forward but am going in circles and would appreciate help. Thanks Newman

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A3:A&"♦"&FILTER(B3:F, B2:F2>="2021-10-07"*1, B2:F2<="2021-10-13"*1)), "♦"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 order by sum(Col2) desc label sum(Col2)''"))
```

and for just 1 record:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A3:A&"♦"&FILTER(B3:F, B2:F2>="2021-10-07"*1, B2:F2<="2021-10-13"*1)), "♦"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 order by sum(Col2) desc label sum(Col2)''"), "limit 1", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write the Query formula. I'll admit I have little experience/knowledge or Query( ).

Comment: Would there be a way to acheve the same result using an array. I have successfully used Sumifs( ) to return the Sum of a row within a date range. I wondered if that could be repeated across all rows in combination with Index( ) to output an array of names and totals ... this could then be fed into a Max( ) or other function to output the name with the largest total.

Comment: @NewmanHard did you try these queries? more on them: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage sum per row can be done in array with MMULT but that can slow down your sheet a bit. can you share a copy of your sheet?